# Regex for key permutations

Tags: regex

k1, k2, ..., kn keywords. For example, given k1, k2, k3 I need to match all following occurrences.

```
k1
k2
k3
k1k2
k1k3
k2k1
k2k3
k3k1
k3k2
k1k2k3
k1k3k2
k2k1k3
k2k3k1
k3k1k2
k3k2k1
```

Logic I have is to create regex for each permutation of k1, k2, ..., kn (n being variable). However this leads to factorial number of regexes - 3! in above example, `k1(k2)?(k3)?`, `k1(k3)?(k2)?`, `k2(k1)?(k3)?`, `k2(k3)?(k1)?`, `k3(k1)?(k2)?`, `k3(k2)?(k1)?` when run sequentially on the same string will get me all above matches.

How can this be made more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However this leads to factorial number of regexes - 3! in above example, k1(k2)?(k3)?, k1(k3)?(k2)?, k2(k1)?(k3)?, k2(k3)?(k1)?, k3(k1)?(k2)?, k3(k2)?(k1)? when run sequentially on the same string will get me all above matches.

That is true.

> How can this be made more efficient?

Use a proper programming language / script to do the job. There you can use loops and generate the needed combinations "easily", without the hassles of regexes.

---

Note: Regexes were not created as a one-for-all tool, and definitely not for complex, algorithmic tasks.

Comment: hmm! you mean regex can't solve this problem? may I ask why, I'm working with regex after a long time. Can we prove the negation that regex by itself won't work?

Comment: Why? You explained it, I just told you that you were right :) With regex **alone**, you cannot generate patterns. You just have the patterns, and you apply them.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions recognize regular languages. Your language is *finite*, so it's regular by definition (you can write a regular expression for it by concatenating all the words with `|` between them), but what characterizes regular languages is *repetitions of patterns*. 
A finite language cannot have arbitrary repetitions, which means that your regexp cannot have any `*` in it. So, it's not a very traditional regular language.
In some cases, the regular expression for a language, in particular a finite language, cannot be *much* simpler than simply listing all the strings of the language. This is one of those cases. The language has a structure, but it's not a structure based on repetitions, so the power of regular expressions is just not aligned with the task/

If you look at the complexity you need in your regular expression (or finite state machine, another way to match regular languages) in order to recognize the strings of your langauge, you can look at the information you need to remember after seeing any prefix of the string.

To recognize `k1k2k3k4` and reject `k1k2k3k1`, `k1k2k3k2`, and `k1k2k3k3`, the information you need to remember after seeing `k1k2k3` is that you have seen `k1`, `k2`, and `k3`.
So, for any sequence of keywords, you must remember the *exact subset of keywords* that has been seen so far. That's roughly exponential in the length of the string seen.

If you have 100 keywords, after seeing 50 of them, you need to remember which 50, and there are K(100,50) possible combinations (aka. 100891344545564193334812497256). That's where the factorial comes from (K(100,50) is 100!/(50!*50!)).
Your regular expression needs to be able to distinguish that many states, because for any two, there is a suffix which will be allowed by one and rejected by the other.